# Simple Audio-editor for PC

Tags: editing, software

A friend of mine wants to learn basic audio editing, 2 or more tracks and asked me what kind of (free) program would be best to use on PC platform... Any idea's?

Answer (score 3):

Audacity is available for PC :http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Should do the job nicely...

Answer (score 2):

Free? Audacity it is!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Cooledit person so have never thought I'd plug Sound Forge but that day has come. Personal thought but I find Audacity frustrating (same with GIMP). So there, spend $65 on Sound Forge Audio Studio (also comes free with Sony recorders) instead. [Read up](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/audiostudio).